Invalid buffer destination, Invalid boost inductor
I have Ubuntu 22.04 dual booted on my HP ENVY x-360 device. While switching to Ubuntu from Windows, several error messages like Invalid boost inductor, Error in Boost DT confi and Invalid buffer destination appear on screen and nothing opens up after that.

